# Why does my code end with: Call to a member function sample_template() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using hierarchical MVC model in codeigniter. I create a controller called template and inside it a function called sample_template. Then a view called sample_template_v created and call it inside the template controller. I create another controller called Admin and called Template->sample_template($data); inside its 2 funtions.

MY_Controlle.php

```
<?php

class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller

{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->module('Template');
    }
}
```

Admin.php

```
<?php

class Admin extends MY_Controller

{

    function __construct()

    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {

        $data['content_view'] = 'admin/admin_v';
        $this->Template->sample_template($data);

    }

    function about()
    {
        $data['content_view'] = 'admin/about_v';
        $this->Template->sample_template($data);
    }

}
```

Template.php

```
<?php

class Template extends MY_Controller

{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function sample_template($data = NULL)
    {
        $this->load->view('Template/sample_template_v', $data);
    }
}
```

sample_template_v.php file---->

```
<h5>This is the main Template.</h5>


<?php $this->load->view($content_view); ?>
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a method from the object you need to initiaze the object and then call a method. Make sure `$this->template is set` in your case it isn't.

```
    $this->template = new Template();

    $this->template->sample_template($data);
```

Comment: Thanks. I manage to solve it. In admin.php I used :                               $this->template->sample_template($data);